# How to update an SVM model with new data

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, computer-vision, scikit-learn

I have two data set with different size.

1) Data set 1 is with high dimensions 4500 samples (sketches).

2) Data set 2 is with low dimension 1000 samples (real data).
I suppose that "both data set have the same distribution"

I want to train an non linear `SVM` model using `sklearn` on the first data set (as a pre-training ), and after that I want to update the model on a part of the second data set (to fit the model).
How can I develop a kind of update on sklearn. How can I update a SVM model?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In sklearn you can do this only for linear kernel and using `SGDClassifier` (with appropiate selection of loss/penalty terms, loss should be hinge, and penalty L2). Incremental learning is supported through `partial_fit` methods, and this is not implemented for neither `SVC` nor `LinearSVC`.

Unfortunately, in practise fitting SVM in incremental fashion for such small datasets is rather useless. SVM has easy obtainable **global solution**, thus you **do not need pretraining of any form**, in fact it should **not matter at all**, if you are thinking about pretraining in the neural network sense. If correctly implemented, SVM should completely forget previous dataset. Why not learn on the whole data in one pass? This is what SVM is supposed to do. Unless you are working with some non-convex modification of SVM (then pretraining makes sense).

To sum up:

- From theoretical and practical point of view there is no point in pretraining SVM. You can either learn only on the second dataset, or on both in the same time. Pretraining is **only** reasonable for methods which suffer from local minima (or hard convergence of any kind) thus need to start near actual solution to be able to find reasonable model (like neural networks). SVM is **not one of them**.
- You can use incremental fitting (although in sklearn it is very limited) for efficiency reasons, but for such small dataset you will be just fine fitting whole dataset at once.

Comment: What if your hypothesis was that the first dataset contained 50% of the information a good model needed, and the smaller datasets would each contain some additional unknown percentage?  I want to make predictions using the first model (50%) from day one because it achieves the criteria, say "autonomous decision making", but I also want to update the model as the new data comes.  My update consists of "lop off bad branches" or "completely retrain".  Are you aware of any algorithm implementations like this?