# Machine learning: Updating weights from true labeled data

Tags: python, machine-learning

Definition of the problem:

- I am having some data with lets say 2 features but there not labeled.
- I manually create weights and label the data with a score
- I present the data to a user with order and the user gives his own score
- By the feedback of the user I want to update the weights, assign the new scores and give back the list in the new order.
- This should continue everytime the user give new labels

In a point of view is a pairwise online learning to rank problem.

A simple Illustration:

Assuming I am having the following data which are not labeled:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [1, 1], [2, 1]])
```

I create manually weights and label the data (which doesnt mean that this weights are the 'correct' so we aren't sure that the labels are the correct one). With the mannually create weights the labels are the following:

```
Y = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2])
```

And I am training a `SGD` stochastic gradient descent algorithm using `sklearn` ,with ‘hinge’ loss which give linear SVM (used for 'learning to rank'):

```
from sklearn import linear_model
clf = linear_model.SGDClassifier()
clf.fit(X, Y)
```

After a period I am getting the correct labels of some of the previous data(name it `true_data`  and use `partial_fit` to fit it in the previous model:

```
x_true_data = np.array([[-1,-1]])
y_true_data = np.array([1])
clf.partial_fit(x_new,y_new)
```

This update the weights. Some concerns that I have gennerally:

- is there a way to 'reward' the previous algorithm if it predicted correctly the result or do the opposite if not of the `true_data`? Something similar as adaboost works.
- How reliable this algorithm would be if the `true_data` data is not many ( between 5-20)
- Can i adjust the learning rate in order to give higher 'value' to the `true_data`?
- Is there another way to think the problem? Should I consider other algorithms except SVM?

Some links that I fould usefull but didnt clear my mind if I sould continue in this path:

[How to update an SVM model with new data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35492556/how-to-update-an-svm-model-with-new-data/35492991#35492991)

[log.regression vs SGDClassifier](http://osdir.com/ml/python-scikit-learn/2012-06/msg00162.html)

Any feedback is welcome.

Comment: This belongs on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), not StackOverflow.

Comment: I would approach this from a regression perspective, since you want to find an ordering for your data